# Change parabola's direction to follow mouse drag

Tags: c#, math, direction, calculus

Im trying to calculate the parabolic trail left in water if an object gets dragged along the surface.
I thought using the locus method with Focus, vertex and directrix would be the way to go. which works well for vertical and horizontal movement (depending on directrix axis) but with the directrix constantly moving its axis direction I'm stuck.

this is what i have now (written for vertical movement)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class Parabola : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject pointD, pointF, pointM;
public LineRenderer line;

public Vector3 mouse=Vector3.one, prev;
public Vector3 directrix;
public Vector3 focusPoint, directrixPointMid, directrixPointL, directrixPointR;
public float directrixLength;
public int resolution;
public Vector3 focalLine;
public float focalLenght;
public Vector3 p;
public List<Vector3> points = new List<Vector3>();

void Start () 
{
    prev = mouse;
    line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    line.positionCount = resolution;
}

void Update () 
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, 1<<LayerMask.NameToLayer("Plane")))
        {
            mouse = new Vector3(hit.point.x,0,hit.point.z);
            if(prev != mouse)
            {
                focalLine = prev - mouse;
                focusPoint = mouse + focalLine.normalized * focalLenght;
                directrixPointMid = mouse +(-focalLine.normalized  * focalLenght);
                directrix = Vector3.Cross(directrixPointMid-focusPoint, Vector3.up);
                directrixPointL = directrixPointMid +(directrix.normalized * (directrixLength/2));
                directrixPointR = directrixPointMid +(-directrix.normalized * (directrixLength/2));

                Debug.DrawRay(mouse, focalLine.normalized*10,Color.green);
                Debug.DrawRay(directrixPointR, directrix.normalized*directrixLength,Color.red);

                pointD.transform.position = directrixPointMid;
                pointF.transform.position = focusPoint;
                pointM.transform.position = mouse;
                prev = mouse;
            }
        }
        points = new List<Vector3>();
        for(float i = -directrixLength/2; i<=directrixLength/2; i+=directrixLength/resolution)
        {
            //float angle = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.forward,focalLine);

            float z = 1/(2*(focusPoint.z-directrixPointMid.z))*Mathf.Pow((Mathf.Abs(directrixPointMid.x)+i)-focusPoint.x,2)+0.5f*(focusPoint.z+directrixPointMid.z);
            float x = directrixPointMid.x+i;
            p = new Vector3(x,1,z);

            //p = new Vector3(x*Mathf.Cos(angle)-z*Mathf.Sin(angle),1,x*Mathf.Sin(angle) + z*Mathf.Cos(angle));
            //p.z = 2*p.x + Mathf.Sin(p.x);
            //p = new Vector3(p.x*Mathf.Cos(angle)-p.z*Mathf.Sin(angle),1,p.x*Mathf.Sin(angle) + p.z*Mathf.Cos(angle));

            points.Add(p);
        }
        line.SetPositions(points.ToArray());

    }
}
}
```

there are some commented out attempts but nothing working.
[image: screen shot of parabola]

Comment: What “parabolic trail” would that be? Is this supposed to be the bow wave? Is that really a parabola, and how is that parabola characterized? I would assume that a point shaped object would leave a triangular (or 2d cone) bow wave, while for extended objects the shape of the bow wave depends on the shape of the object. So please try to add additional constraints to uniquely characterize the parabola you want.

Comment: yes after i get it to follow the direction of the mouse drag, i'll add in variables to change the steepness and such.
but that still doesn't solve my problem atm.

Comment: i changed it to just use y=x^2; (or in my case z=x^2;) and made everything local. so now it works. If i get it perfect, i'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my set up to use y = x^2 and made all my coordinates local to the direction of dragging.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Parabola : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject linePrefab, pointV;

public float offset, amp, speed;
public int freq;
public float directrixLength;
public int resolution;

private Vector3 mouse, prev;
private Vector3 directrix;
private Vector3 focusPoint, directrixPointMid, directrixPointL, directrixPointR;
private Vector3 focalLine;
private Vector3 p;
private List<List<Vector3>> pointsR = new List<List<Vector3>>();
private List<LineRenderer> lines = new List<LineRenderer>();
public Renderer render;

void Start () 
{
    render.material.SetInt("_Length", resolution);
    render.material.SetVectorArray("_Points", new Vector4[resolution]); 

    prev = mouse;
    int i = 0;
    while(i <= freq)
    {
        GameObject g = Instantiate(linePrefab);
        g.transform.SetParent(transform);
        g.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        LineRenderer line = g.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        line.positionCount = resolution;
        lines.Add(line);
        List<Vector3> lR = new List<Vector3>();
        pointsR.Add(lR);
        i++;
    }
}

void FixedUpdate () 
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, 1<<LayerMask.NameToLayer("Plane")))
        {
            mouse = new Vector3(hit.point.x,0,hit.point.z);
            StopCoroutine(CalculateParabola(mouse));
            StartCoroutine(CalculateParabola(mouse));
            transform.position = mouse;
            transform.forward = -focalLine;
        }
    }
}
IEnumerator CalculateParabola(Vector3 v)
{
    while(prev != v)
    {
        focalLine = prev - v;
        //calculate a parabola for each n in frequency, make it go wider the higher n is
        for(int n=0; h<=freq; n++)
        {
            pointsR[n] = new List<Vector3>();
            float s = Vector3.Distance(prev.normalized,v.normalized)*speed;
            for(float i = -directrixLength/2; i<=(directrixLength+1)/2; i+=directrixLength/resolution)
            {
                p.x = pointV.transform.localPosition.x+(i*(freq-n+Time.fixedDeltaTime*s));
                p.z = ((amp*(freq-n))*(Time.fixedDeltaTime*s))*-Mathf.Pow(p.x,2)+(1+offset*n);
                pointsR[n].Add(p);
            }
            lines[h].SetPositions(pointsR[n].ToArray());
            //attempt to translate the points to a shader, only for the first parabola for now
            Vector4[] renderPoints = new Vector4[resolution];
            for(int i=0; i<resolution; i++)
            {
                renderPoints[i] = transform.TransformPoint(pointsR[0][i]) - render.transform.position;
            }
            render.material.SetVectorArray("_Points", renderPoints); 
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        prev = v;
    }
}
}
```